# Greensock, jquery, code does not fire in chrome?

Tags: gsap

I  have no idea why, but for some reason my code does not fire in chrome. Any idea why? I read the entire documentation of Greensock but nothing that adresses my issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/w0otqcw8/6/

```
var t = TweenLite.to(".menu-button", 4, {left:'0', opacity:'0.9', ease:Bounce.easeOut, paused:true, reversed:true});

$(".menu-button").on("click", function() {
  if (t.reversed()) {
    t.play();
  } else {
    t.reverse();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code adds right and left css properties at the same time. Animate x,y,xPercent and yPercent instead.